# what is sql server management studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-express

What is SQL Server Management Studio? Is it the whole SQL SERVER software OR just an interface to operate SQL SERVER software.

Comment: it is a client tool. It provides access to SQL Server (the server bit)

Comment: See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174173.aspx - it's your "front-end tool" to see what SQL Server contains, to query SQL Server, and to do other admin/dev tasks. It's definitely **NOT** the *whole* SQL Server - it's just the pretty (debatable) UI to work with SQL Server directly

Comment: does exactly what it says in the name, software to manage your Sql Server databases

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server management studio is just the IDE for making access to SQL Server easier.

Answer (score 1):

It is an interface to help you talk to SQL Server. SQL Server Books Online is an excellent resource to get you started, if you want to find out more: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=be6a2c5d-00df-4220-b133-29c1e0b6585f&DisplayLang=en

Comment: Its Express edition is free to download and use, along with the SQL Server Express. I don't know if you can redistribute it, though.

Comment: i want to send mail using sql server. if i use sql server express but download sql server management studio (non-express) then i can i send mails.